# Why does this plot produce a totally different result when the number doesn't change?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am doing the Udacity course deep learning and ran into some trouble. In the code below, if I remove the "axis=0" option in the sum in the softmax function, the same number is still printed but a totally different plot is shown. Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Here is the code:

```
scores = [3.0, 1.0, 0.2]    
import numpy as np

def softmax(x):
    return(np.exp(x)/np.sum(np.exp(x), axis=0))

print(softmax(scores))

# Plot softmax curves
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.arange(-2.0, 6.0, 0.1)
scores = np.vstack([x, np.ones_like(x), 0.2 * np.ones_like(x)])

plt.plot(x, softmax(scores).T, linewidth=2)
plt.show();
```

Appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Axis is an indicator of which values you want to take in your numpy value
[image: Axis]

So you have to indicate which values you want to consider.

Comment: Thank you! I see that and I think that axis=0 is the default since it returns the same values if I remove it. The weird thing is that the plot somehow looks totally different even though the function actually returns the same value.